# is this font called Computer Modern, is there a way to find out which font I am using on overleaf?

Tags: fonts

this code `$\mathcal{Y}$` generates this symbol by default on overleaf

[image]

is this font called Computer Modern, designed by Donald Knuth?

is there a way to find out which font I am using on overleaf?

Comment: You can have the list of fonts in the resulting .pdf from the `File -> Properties` menu in most pdf viewers.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. It shows CMR10 and CMSY10, does both of them work together?

Comment: cmr10 is the default font for text,cmsy10 is a symbols maths font, which probably (I didn't check) contains the math calligraphic glyphs.

Comment: @Bernard  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, I'm sure there's already (at least) an answer on this subject. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Not sure about that; I didn't see answers in that question specific to Overleaf.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii This is not specific to Overleaf. And the "accepted" in comment solution is a short version of the first answer in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: The question seemed specific to Overleaf to me.  If I'm wrong, then this is definitely a duplicate.